# Moving Outlook encryption configuration to a new machine

Tags: encryption, email, microsoft-outlook

My outlook configuration is currently set to encrypt all outgoing mail.

I wish to migrate all encryption settings to a new PC. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Encryption in outlook requires a digital ID (public/private key certificate). To continue to use the same ID on a new machine you would have to install the same certificate there.

Comment: Will Importing the outlook profile with same credentials be of help?

Comment: @Nagarajan - I don't know for certain as I don't use this in outlook but I expect Digital IDs are stored in the windows certificate store. So I don't believe they would be exported as part of the outlook profile by default.